# Intergration of Hyperledger Fabric chaincode with Frontent using APIs

Tags: node.js, api, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to integrate my chaincode with the frontend by creating APIs. I am currently using the chaincode from fabric-samples (/asset-basic-transfer/chaincode-javascript).

If I try to create the APIs using the traditional way, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'putState' of undefined

I am getting the error when I use:
`await ctx.stub.putState(id, Buffer.from(stringify(sortKeysRecursive(asset))));`.

When I just call the function using:
`assetTransfer.CreateAsset(ctx, id, data)` - I get an error saying that `CreateAsset is not a function.`

How to fix this error? Or, alternatively, how to create APIs that can be called?

Comment: Please add your source code.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth making sure you understand the key concepts of a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain network, and how the different components relate:

- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/network/network.html#invoking-a-smart-contract
- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/smartcontract/smartcontract.html

A chaincode (or smart contract) runs at the server side and is invoked by an endorsing peer in response to client proposals. So you would not invoke chaincode functions or APIs directly from your application layer. Instead, you should look to use one of the Fabric application APIs to submit or evaluate transactions that will drive your deployed smart contract:

- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/getting_started.html#hyperledger-fabric-application-sdks

Your application layer would provide an API that can be invoked by your frontend, and would use a Fabric application API to interact with Fabric on behalf of the frontend.